# regex for only whitespace alone, not white-space in between characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, what is the regex for alone spaces, not spaces between characters?

`\s+` works for all whitespace.

What I am trying to do is if the string is just whitespace and not white-space with other characters, then do something.

Here is what I have so far: `if(/regexp/i.exec(str) !== null) // do something`

Comment: Note that the dup answer also matches empty strings. To match one or more spaces, use `^\s+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if (/^\s+$/i.test(str)) {
    // string contains only whitespaces
}
```

Comment: Sorry hadn't seen your post. Your solution is the same as mine, so +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.replace(/\s/g, "").length===0)
{


}
```

Replaces all the white spaces left and if no other character is left then the length should be 0